# Cross-platform way to create a boost::function from function pointer

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, gcc, boost

I've been writing some templates that expect to be passed a boost::function.  They determine the arguments to the boost::function and then use that to create an appropriate specialization of a class.  For example, this is the template for 0 arguments:

```
template< class ReturnT >
MyFunctionPtr MakeFunction( boost::function< ReturnT (  ) > func )
{
    return MyFunctionPtr( new MyFunction< decltype( func ), ReturnT >( func ) );
}
```

As a bit of a shortcut I've got another version of the MakeFunction template that takes in a function pointer and automatically wraps it in a boost::function of the appropriate type:

```
template< class T >
MyFunctionPtr MakeFunctionFromPointer( T func )
{
    return MakeFunction( 
        boost::function< typename boost::remove_pointer<T>::type >( func )
        );
}
```

This allows me to create from function pointers without explicitly passing in the function spec:

```
int something() { return 1; }
MakeFunctionFromPointer( &something );
```

On MSVC this is working fine but with GCC 4.3 I get "no matching function" errors.  It appears that:

On MSVC `boost::remove_pointer< bool (*)() >::type` is `bool ()`

But on GCC 4.3: `boost::remove_pointer< bool (*)() >::type` is `bool ()()`

So on GCC an appropriate template of MakeFunction does not exist.

Is there any way I can alter the output on remove_pointer output on either platform to match the other?  Or is there an other way I can go about solving this problem?

Comment: Maybe try `boost::decay` instead of `remove_pointer`...

Comment: @KerrekSB That seems to result in `bool (*)()`, which `boost::function` doesn't accept.

Comment: How about `template <typename T> MakeFunctionFromPointer(T(*f)()) { return boost::function<T()>(f); }`?

Comment: @KerrekSB Yeah, that works.  I was hoping to avoid having to define an overload for each of the different numbers of arguments, but guess it might be unavoidable.  If you put this as an answer, I'll accept if nothing better comes along.

Comment: Well, you could use variadic templates in general...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly take a pointer as the function argument, and infer the function type from that:

```
template< class T >
MyFunctionPtr MakeFunctionFromPointer( T * func )
{
    return MakeFunction( boost::function<T>( func ) );
}
```

UPDATE: based on your comment below, it looks like the problem is that you declare `MakeFunction` *after* using it in the definition of `MakeFunctionFromPointer`. Either my version, or yours using `boost::remove_pointer`, should be fine as long as all functions are declared before use.

Comment: This seems to suffer from the same issue on GCC.  T is `bool ()()`

Comment: Yeah, that simple example works.  It's missing the bit where I pass the resulting boost::function in to `MakeFunction( boost::function<  ReturnT () > )` though, which is where my problem lies.

Comment: @obmarg: There's [no problem](http://ideone.com/vVXid) there either (although I'm missing the real `MyFunction` type). Could you post a compilable example that shows the problem you're having?

Comment: http://ideone.com/Ro76v shows the problem that I'm having.  Though now that I've played about a bit, it may just be down to the order I've declared functions in.

Comment: @obmarg: That is indeed the problem, at least with the code you posted there. Swapping the two function overloads, or declaring the second before the first, fixes the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a type-deducing maker function template:

```
template <typename R>
boost::function<R()> make_function(R(*f)())
{ return boost::function<R()>(f); }

template <typename R, typename ...Args>
boost::function<R(Args...)> make_function(R(*f)(Args...))
{ return boost::function<R(Args...)>(f); }
```

If your compiler doesn't support variadic templates, you can use something like Microsoft's preprocessor hack to simulate them (e.g. see the [pretty printer source code](https://raw.github.com/louisdx/cxx-prettyprint/master/prettyprint.hpp) for an example).